OutOfMemoryException when using Java HttpClient to send big file
I am using this approach to send file via Java HttpClient: How to define multiple parameters for a POST request using Java 11 HTTP Client
However, if the file is big ( just like 300MB ) . I will get OutOfMemoryException :
java.io.IOException: Java heap space
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:593)
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:123)

However can I improve the sending logic to prevent using too much memory?

Try sending the file in chunks using InputStreams instead of loading and sending entire file. Change HttpClient to send request with stream by adding header with Content-Type set to "application/octet-stream"
